# Show that the Mathematical expectation of what the man earns is $\frac {S}{n (2n-1)}$

Tags: probability, expected-value

A bag contains $2n$  counters of which half are marked with odd numbers and half with even numbers, the sum of all the numbers being $S$. A man is to draw two counters. If the sum of the numbers drawn is odd, he is to receive that number if dollars; if even, he has to pay that amount of dollars. Show that his expectation is $\dfrac {S}{n(2n-1)}$

**Attempt:** Let the odd numbers be $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n \}$ and the even numbers be $\{b_1,\cdots,b_n \}$

Let $X_{i,1}, X_{i,2}$ represent the $i_{th}$ counters. Let $X_i$ be an indicator variable which takes the value $1$ if $X_{i,1}+ X_{i,2} $ is odd and the value $-1$ if $X_{i,1}, X_{i,2}$ is even.

Then $P(X_i=1) = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 2= \dfrac{1}{2};~P(X_i=-1)=\dfrac {n}{2n} \cdot \dfrac {n-1}{2n} \cdot 2=\dfrac {n-1}{2n}$

Thus, $E[X_i]= \dfrac{1}{2}~[ ~\sum_{k=1}^n a_k - \dfrac {n-1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n b_k ~]~=\dfrac{1}{2} [S - \dfrac {2n-1}{n}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n b_k ]$

$\sum_1^n E[X_i]=\dfrac{n}{2} [S - \dfrac {2n-1}{n}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n b_k ]$

I feel stuck here. Could someone please show me a direction from here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can he draw the sum number twice (for example, could he draw two times $a_1$ on the same go?)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I would assume no as The question doesn't mention anything like that

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Revised my probabilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it is more likely that the sum of his numbers is odd than that it is even:

- There is a total of $(2n)\cdot(2n-1)$ possible choices.
- If the sum of the two chosen numbers should be odd, then that means that he chose $(a_i, b_{\tilde i})$ or $(b_i,a_{\tilde i})$ for any $i,\tilde i=1\dots n$. So there are $2\cdot (n\cdot n)$ choices such that the sum is odd.
- However, for even numbers, we must have either $(a_i, a_{\tilde i})$ or $(b_i,b_{\tilde i})$ for some **distinct** $i,\tilde i$. So there are $2\cdot (n\cdot (n-1))$ choices.

Hence, $\mathbb P(\text{odd sum})=\frac{n}{2n-1}$ and $\mathbb P(\text{even sum})=\frac{n-1}{2n-1}$.

Let $W$ denote the win. Then $$\mathbb E(W)=\frac{n}{2n-1}\cdot\mathbb E(W\mid \text{odd sum})+\frac{n-1}{2n-1}\cdot\mathbb E(W\mid \text{even sum}).$$

Now (tiny exercise), note that $-\mathbb E(W\mid \text{even sum})=\mathbb E(W\mid \text{odd sum})=\frac{S}{n}$. Hence,
$$\mathbb E(W)=\frac{S}{n\cdot(2n-1)}.$$

Comment: Could you please explain how: $-\mathbb E(W\mid \text{even sum})=\mathbb E(W\mid \text{odd sum})=\frac{S}{n}$ . I get the sum as expectation as $nS$

Comment: @MathMan We have $$\mathbb E(W\mid\text{odd sum})=\mathbb E(\text{win from the } a_i)+\mathbb E(\text{win from the } b_i)=\frac1n \cdot\sum_{i=1}^n a_i + \frac1n \cdot\sum_{i=1}^n b_i=\frac Sn.$$ Similarly, $$-\mathbb E(W\mid\text{even sum})=\frac12\cdot(\mathbb E(\text{win from two distinct } a_i) + \mathbb E(\text{win from two distinct } b_i))=\frac1n \cdot\left(\sum_i a_i + \sum_i b_i\right)=\frac Sn.$$ I recommend that you try it out with the four counters $1,2,3,4$ to get some intuition

Comment: How did you come up with this expression: This is what I don't understand actually : $$\mathbb E(W)=\frac{n}{2n-1}\cdot\mathbb E(W\mid \text{odd sum})+\frac{n-1}{2n-1}\cdot\mathbb E(W\mid \text{even sum}).$$

Comment: @MathMan It is the [Law of total expectation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) for the two events "sum odd" and "sum even"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer

Comment: Could also have a look here please: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3407534/show-that-the-co-variance-between-x-j-and-x-k-is-frac-pqn-1-j-ne-k